# Best way to show multiple images fetched from Api in uiscrollview at runtime in iphone?

Tags: iphone

Hey i am working on iphone application where i am fetching data from an API xml format.my data  contains thousands of images.I am using nsxml parsing  and ASIHttp library to show data in uiscrollview . but it is very time consuming and also  sometimes i have to make multiple calls to api in single page. so please anyone suggest me best way to parse data in background or asynchrounasly and show it in chuncks in uiscrollview please help me with the code.
thanking you in advance...